# /sys/class/scsi_host/host0 not found - get it back without reboot?

Tags: linux, scsi

I have a oracle linux 5.8 virtual server (virtualized via oracle virtual manager, which is using xen), which has a couple of luns attached via scsi. Now I wanted to attache more luns, but found that /sys/class/scsi_host/host0, which is the scsi host where the lun would be attached, is missing. It must have been there bevor, because I was able to attach the previous luns.

I have a feeling that rebooting the box would fix things, but since this is production, a reboot would cause some hassle.

Any ideas as to why this could be missing or how to get it back without a reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your  `multipath -ll` yield (if you are using multipath) ?

Comment: It outputs among other things "DM multipath kernel driver not loaded" ... i guess that is the problem.

Comment: Except if you are actually using something else than multipath... But if you are using it (depends on your distrib), start the `multipathd` daemon, or the `boot.multipathd`etc.